# ICollection ClearAndAddRange share reference?

Tags: c#, reference, icollection

I have two `ICollection` lists `fullList` and `displayList`.

```
private void method()
{
    if(condition != null) {
        displayList.Clear();
        if(fullList.Count() > 0)
        {
            displayList.ClearAndAddRange(
                           fullList.Where(x=>x.conditionID == condition.conditionID));

        }
    }

}
```

The problem I'm currently facing is whenever I update some value in `displayList`, `fullList` gets also updated . Is this expected behaviour?

What is the best way to modify it so that they won´t share references in between?

Comment: `ICollection` does not have such method. Is it a custom implementation of some sort? Did you assign the same instance to the different variables by any chance?

Comment: Use a projection with '.select(x => new {...})’. I can't code it without knowing what your collections contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed expected behaviour. Consider the following two lists:

```
var list1 = new[] { myObj1, myObj2 };
var list2 = list1;

list2[0].myProp = 3;
```

where `myObj1` and `myObj2` are instances of `MyClass`.

As `list1` and `list2` share the same references to the contained objects all modifications made to any of those items will be reflected in the other list also. When you want to avoid this behavioour you have to provide a deep-copy which will create an entriely new instance of your objects:

```
var list2 = list1.Select(x => new MyClass { ... });
```

For further information on deep cloning also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically).